# Unable to attach with sqlcipher encrypted database to another one

Tags: database, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I'm working on an app that is using a database that is encrypted by sqlcipher. The passwort for this encryption is stored by cacheword.

To make a backup of my database I used the following code:

```
// ggf. Datenbank öffnen
openGuard();
mDb.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + outFileName + "' AS backup KEY 'asdfghjkl';");
mDb.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('backup');");
mDb.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE backup;");
```

The method openGuard() is used to check if the database is opend yet and if not do this.

I've checked the backup by using an empty key to make an unencrypted copy of my database. Then I can use it on adb shell and use sql-statements to get the wanted data.

My problem now for a long time is that I'm not able to use my backup to restore the database of my app. I tried this code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(backupFile, "asdfghjkl", null);
db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + dbFile + "' AS encrypted KEY '" + mCacheWord.getEncryptionKey() + "';");
db.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted')");
db.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE encrypted;");
```

Alternatively I tried

```
db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + dbFile + "' AS encrypted KEY '" + encodeRawKey(mCacheWord.getEncryptionKey()) + "';");
```

But in both cases I get the following error message:

```
10-30 00:56:42.845: I/Database(14407): sqlite returned: error code = 26, msg = statement aborts at 5: [ATTACH DATABASE '/data/data/.../databases/database.db' AS encrypted KEY '[B@42082da0';] file is encrypted or is not a database
10-30 00:56:42.845: E/Database(14407): Failure 26 (file is encrypted or is not a database) on 0x63bdedb0 when executing 'ATTACH DATABASE '/data/data/.../databases/database.db' AS encrypted KEY '[B@42082da0';'
```

Is there anyone how can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've gotten accidentally "hung up" trying to decrypt by supplying the key via the **`ATTACH DATABASE`** statement. Looking at **[Example 2: Decrypt a SQLCipher database to a Plaintext Database](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/)** of the API, there's a comment that reads **`-- empty key will disable encryption`**. So, presumably your initial decryption code attempt should first execute the **`PRAGMA key =`** statement (to supply the key) and then the **`ATTACH DATABASE`** statement **with empty key** (to decrypt) something like this:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA key = '" + mCacheWord.getEncryptionKey() + "';");
db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + dbFile + "' AS encrypted KEY '';");
db.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted')");
db.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE encrypted;");
```

Another brief example about this can be seen in this **[the SQLCipher Users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlcipher/e34opBbq4Dw/_iMiZXNOCw8J)** discussion.

Comment: I recently checked this suggestion, but it doesn't help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem may have to do with the fact that you are using CacheWord, which manages the encryption key separately from SQLCipher. You should verify the format of the string returned from getEncryptionKey() and ensure that it matches the proper format for a raw key in SQLCIpher.

Comment: I think this is the problem, but I don't know how to solve it. But I helped me by attaching the backup to the app's database and then copying the values of each table. This means more code, but it works. Thanks!